# Dynamic Linq creates multiple queries

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

The following linq call in plain linq to sql results in 1 SQL query to the database

```
Table1.Select(t => new {Table2.First().Property1})
```

But I can't seem to get Dynamic Linq to to the same, the below produces 2 separate queries.

```
Table1.Select("new(@0.Property1)", Table2.First())
```

This does not work either

```
Table1.Select("@0", Table2.First().Property1)
```

or this

```
Table1.Select("new(@0 as MyField)", Table2.First().Property1)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jeff's insights the correct query arrangement should be

```
Table1.Select(t => new {t2 = Table2.First()}).Select("new(t2.Property1)")
```

which produces a single query call to the DB

Answer (score 0):

It's generating two separate queries because in that context, `Table2.First()` is a separate call from the rest of the query. It's not integrated into the generated expression.  It's as if you did this:

```
var first = Table2.First(); // evaluated eagerly due to the First() call
var query = Table1.Select("new(@0.Property1)", first);
```

You can achieve the desired result if you rewrote it in terms of a cartesian product with the second table.

```
var query = Table1.SelectMany(t1 =>
        Table2.Take(1).Select(t2 => new { t1, t2 })
    )
    .Select("new(t2.Property1 as MyField)");
```

Comment: I get an error, "No Property or Field t2 exists on IQueryable`1"

Comment: Sorry, there should be an `it` there.

Comment: Should not need the it, as the context is already implicit. Either way this still did not work. Reason why was that the query was returning an IOrderedQueryable<IQueryable<>>, so no wonder it could not find the property t2. Found the correct query as posted below.

Comment: The query does not produce an `IOrderedQueryable<IQueryable<>>`. Were you actually using `SelectMany()`? That was the whole point.

Comment: Nope, just using Select(). Just rewrote the above code to make sure again (without the last dynamic select as last time) and I definitely get a IOrderedQueryable<IQueryable<>>. I'm just referencing 2 random tables from my SQL server via LinqPad.

Comment: Well that's the problem. You would have needed to use it exactly as I wrote it out. Anyway, we'll get nowhere if you don't actually provide the actual query you are using. You'll get the _expected_ result if you followed the example.